# Which smartwatches have autorestart timers?

Tags: android, smart-device, wearable-technology

Please advise of any smartwatches that have timers that autorestart features namely where dismiss and reset are in one swipe and swipes are required or how certain smartwatch alarms can achieve such.

Context:

I had previously asked about [Pomodoro](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30949/countdown-timer-or-pomodoro-for-android-that-is-automatically-restarted-but-asks/39551#39551) or [HIIT](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31167/hiit-timer-variant-for-android) timer variants that have an autoreset feature unlike timer but still asked to be dismissed. Do Android smartwatches have something like what [I Can't Wake Up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kog.alarmclock&hl=en) has?

Example:

Let's say it is 11:59am. I want to be reminded of the time at 12:05pm and then be reminded every 5 minutes.

Currently, I am using my phone.

So either I set a timer for 5 minutes when it's 12pm or I set an alarm to ring at 12:05pm. If timer: I want an option to autorestart after dismiss (so far I haven't found any). If alarm: I want an option to snooze not so easily (with I Can't Wake Up, I can make it so that I have to slide up to snooze or slide down to dismiss).

But it's a hassle to get my phone out every time wherein sometimes I have to first unlock the phone first snoozing the alarm (I Can't Wake Up has 'Quit Block', but I have yet to try this).

I'm hoping some smartwatch has the ability to go off at 12:05pm or 5 minutes after I set the timer (which would be around 12pm) so that I just have to swipe my watch instead of taking out my phone.

I haven't been able to find such features for any smartwatch, but I may be using wrong keywords.